# How to access attribute of superclass instance from child class method

Tags: python, class

I have the following class structure in my code:
A superclass, A, which is basically a list of objects from a subclass, B.  Class A has a method, meth, which creates a variable, var, (by reading from a file).  The variable, var, needs to be accessible by a method of the subclass B.  The problem is that after initialising a = A(), var is a attribute of the instance a, which can't be accessed by subclass methods using super().  var is a large array of floats (around 1e5 elements), so i'm trying to minimise memory usage by not making it an attribute of an instance of B (n times!) or passing it explicitly to methB.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self,n):
    self.data = [B() for _ in xrange(n)]

  def __getitem__(self,n):
    return self.data[n]

  def methA(self):
    with open('file.txt','r') as fp:
      self.var = fp.readlines()

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    self.derived_var = []

  def methB():
    '''This method needs to use var defined in meth of A above.'''

a = A(5)
a.methA()
for b in A:
  b.methB()
```

Is this possible in python or is it bad coding??

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't see the point of defining `B` as a subclass of `A`. They don't seem to share functionalites and you create circular reference between `B` and `A` (in the constructor of `A`) which might lead to problems.

Now as for your question. Is it a problem to just pass `a.var` to `methB`? Like this:

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    self.derived_var = []

  def methB(self, var):
    # some code

a = A(5)
a.meth()
for b in A:
  b.methB(a.var)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  A follow up question:  If I pass a large numpy array to a function/method, does it actually pass a pointer or the array itself.  i.e. do I have to worry about choking up my memory if i call the function a large number of times?

Comment: @user1098683 Everything in Python is passed via reference. You don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def methB(self):
    super(B, self).meth()
    print self.var
```

Using `super()` can help you get the attribute defined in the super class. But the inheritance should be a *is-one* relationship. Your design is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use classes when functions suffice:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as fp:
    var = fp.readlines()

for _ in xrange(5):
    funcB()
```

So much simpler. If you *do* want to use a class, you need to show us why using a class is desireable.

Comment: -1: he definitely doesn't have to show us why he is using classes. This is irrelevant to the question. And your answer is not an answer at all.

Comment: How can we give a proper class-based solution when he hasn't made it clear why B is a subclass of A and yet A contains a list of B's? Should we be using inheritance or composition? would one class suffice? Why define `self.var` in `methA` instead of making `var` a class attribute or a memoized value? There are so many possible solutions it is impossible to give a good solution without knowing more details. Without it, you are likely providing an ad hoc solution to a bad design. Until he gives those details, the best solution is the simplest, which is no class at all.